# Login authentication using Firebase unsuccessful

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to login with credentials same as I used while registration. Firebase already has entries of registered users. Every time I try to login it displays "Login Unsuccessful" I don't see any problem with the code. Please help.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private EditText email_login, password_login;
private TextView register_login;
private Button button_login;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View userLoginFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);


    email_login = (EditText) userLoginFragment.findViewById(R.id.email_login);
    password_login = (EditText) userLoginFragment.findViewById(R.id.password_login);
    register_login = (TextView) userLoginFragment.findViewById(R.id.register_login);
    button_login = (Button) userLoginFragment.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());


    button_login.setOnClickListener(this);
    register_login.setOnClickListener(this);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
        ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, profileFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    return userLoginFragment;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == button_login)
        userLogin();

    if (v == register_login) {
        UserRegisterFragment userRegisterFragment = new UserRegisterFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, userRegisterFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}//End of onClick() method

public void userLogin(){
    String email = email_login.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = password_login.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.length() == 0) {
        email_login.setError("Username is required");
        email_login.requestFocus();
    }
    if (password.length() == 0) {
        password_login.setError("Password is required");
        password_login.requestFocus();
    }
    if (email.length()>0 && password.length()>0){
        progressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
        progressDialog.show();
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this.getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginFragment.this.getActivity(), "Login unsuccessful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }

                else{


                    Toast.makeText(LoginFragment.this.getActivity(), "Login successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, profileFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

Comment: go to your firebase console > authentication > sign in method and check if "email/password" is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to show the failure reason:

```
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
    Toast.makeText(LoginFragment.this.getActivity(),
         "Login unsuccessful: " + task.getException().getMessage(), //ADD THIS
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    progressDialog.dismiss();

}
```